# Zoom Multieffect

Tags: electric-guitar, guitar-effects

Is it possible to edit patches of [Zoom G3XN](https://www.zoom.co.jp/products/guitar-bass-effects/guitar/g3xn-multi-effects-processor) on PC?

It would be more convinient than editing them on pedal.

Comment: Surely it will tell you in the instructions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's possible now thanks to the new version of [Guitar Lab v3](https://www.zoom.co.jp/news/GuitarLab_v3). Alternatively you can use [ToneLib](http://tonelib.net/).

Comment: Can you share a bit more information from the link, just in case the link ever goes down?

Answer (score 1):

'Guitar Lab' is offered.  Link below.

https://www.zoom.co.jp/sites/default/files/products/downloads/pdfs/E_GuitarLab_0_0.pdf

Answer (score 1):

No, you can't edit the patches outside of the actual pedal. While *Guitar Lab* can upload, download and organize patches on PC or Mac, it cannot edit them (which is a shame, really).